# Mobile Phone Address bar throwing off Fixed Position

Tags: html, css, parallax

I'm creating parallax images by creating fixed-positioned backgrounds on elements like this:

```
#element:before {
    content: '';
    background: url('sample.jpg') no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-position: 68% center;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Works great, except I noticed that when, on a mobile phone, the address bar comes into view, it actually throws off the positioning of my fixed elements. Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be resolved by dynamically changing the height of the before element:

On the page, just a blank style tag with an ID to target:

```
<style id="values-styles" type="text/css">

</style>
```

Then the JS / jQuery:

```
var valuesStyles = jQuery('#values-styles');

// since window resize is called when the address bar is shown or hidden
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
valuesStyles.html("#values:before { height:" + jQuery(window).height() + "px;}");
});
```

Works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

`position: fixed` has a number of issues in mobile browsers. Unfortunately, it is usually best to avoid using it because of these issues. [Here is an article that outlines these problems in more detail](https://medium.com/@im_rahul/safari-and-position-fixed-978122be5f29).

Essentially, you should try to use `position: absolute` instead.

Answer (score -1):

best solution for me
I change 100vh to 100%

u can look  at [Here is an article that best solution](https://chanind.github.io/javascript/2019/09/28/avoid-100vh-on-mobile-web.html)

Comment: OP is using `height: 100%;` already...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I post this answer of people by same problem "Mobile Phone Address bar throwing off Fixed Position" like me and find can use 100% instead 100vh